# Error Hanling RemainingChargePercentChanged Event

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to update a `textblock` whenever there is a change in battery percent. I found the event `RemainingChargePercentChanged` in the Windows.Phone.Devices.Power.Battery namespace. But whenever the `eventhandler` is called and i try to update the `textblock`, i struck with error.
the error is:

An exception of type `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` occurred in `System.Windows.ni.dll` but was not handled in user code.

Do I want to select any capabilities in `AppManifest` file??.. If so, what?

Any help will be appreciated. 
 Following is my code,

```cs
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly Battery _battery;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _battery = Battery.GetDefault();
        _battery.RemainingChargePercentChanged += OnRemainingChargePercentChanged;
        UpdateUI();    
    }

    private void OnRemainingChargePercentChanged(object sender, object e)
    {
        UpdateUI();
    }

    private void UpdateUI()
    {
        sampletext.Text = string.Format("{0} %", _battery.RemainingChargePercent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the event handler is called on another thread, if you read the exception message it will say `Invalid cross-thread access.`

The solution is to change the `Text` property on the UI thread using the `Dispatcher`, like this:

```cs
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
    sampletext.Text = string.Format("{0} %", _battery.RemainingChargePercent); 
});
```

**Edit:** or your whole UpdateUI function call:

```cs
private void OnRemainingChargePercentChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
        UpdateUI();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works. But one thing I cant understand is first time when the app loads, the textblock text is set and when the event occurs, it doesn't. Can't get that...

Comment: That is weird, I actually tested the code and it updated fine for me even in the event handler.